# Deriving the Curl of the Magnetic Field, Role of the Nabla Operator

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, differentiation

We know that the magnetic field can be written in the following way:

$$\nabla_{\vec r }\times\vec B(\vec r) = \frac 1 c \nabla_{\vec r}\times\int d^3\vec r_q\ \vec j(\vec r_q)\times \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3}$$
and, using the $BAC-CAB$ identity, the curl of this becomes:

$$= \frac 1 c \int d^3\vec r_q\ \vec j(\vec r_q) (\nabla_{\vec r} \cdot \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3})-\frac 1 c \int d^3r_q\ \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3} (\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot \vec j(\vec r_q))$$

with the property, $\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot\frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3}= 4\pi\delta^3(\vec r-\vec r_q)$, we can write this as:

$$=\frac 1 c \int d^3r_q\ \vec j(\vec r_q) 4\pi\delta^3(\vec r-\vec r_q) - \frac 1 c \int d^3r_q\ \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3} (\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot \vec j(\vec r_q))$$

from here, what is usually done is to observe the second integral, and rewrite the integrand as:
$$(\nabla_{\vec r} \cdot \vec j(\vec r_q)) \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3} = (\vec j(\vec r_q) \cdot\nabla_{\vec r} ) \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3} = -(\vec j(\vec r_q)\cdot\nabla_{\vec r_q}) \frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3}$$

and from here, using partial integration and continuity equation for magnetostatics, one gets $0$ for the integrand, and thus the integral.

What I would have done is to say, since $\nabla_{\vec r}$ is a differentiation with respect to $\vec r$, applying it to $\vec j(\vec r_1)$ would give $0$, since $\vec j$ is not dependent on $\vec r$.

I understand that if this were true, people wouldn't get in the trouble of doing all the above algebra, but what I don't understand is the reason why my explanation is false. How can we say that $\nabla_{\vec r}$ acts on $\frac {\vec r-\vec r_q}{|\vec r-\vec r_q|^3}$, when it can also be interpreted as acting on $\vec j(\vec r_q)$?

Answer (score 1):

The BAC-CAB identity does not apply here as $\nabla$ is an operator. The correct product rule to use is
$$\nabla\times(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}) = (\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A} - (\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}) - \mathbf{B}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}).$$

Applying it to this equation, taking $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{B} = (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')/|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3$, we see that the first and last terms are automatically zero as $\mathbf{J}$ does not depend on $\mathbf{r}$. Therefore, only the second and third terms remain and the argument proceeds as you stated.

This is covered in section 5.3 of Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*.